# Can't get started with modal popup using magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I've read the documentation of Magnific Popup, included the files and just copied and pasted the code from the modal popup as per the following 
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6c5f/)

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">Open modal</a>

<div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
        <h1>Modal dialog</h1>

    <p>You won't be able to dismiss this by usual means (escape or click button), but you can close it programatically based on user choices or actions.</p>
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a>
    </p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#username',
        modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

But this isn't working at all, what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: what errors are thrown in console? Did you include jQuery and plugin files?

Comment: I get no errors to the console. You may see the jsfiddle with the external references in my link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably problem with your externally loaded CSS in your JsFiddle. Try to remove externally loaded css and paste the content into CSS tab.